# Regex: getting all the hashtags and mentions used in all my documents

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using the Kibana console to perform such queries (they are separated: one for the hashtags, one for the mentions). The collection of documents are blog entries with a textContent field, which may have user mentions like @theUserName @AnotherOne or hashtags like #helloWorld and #hello2. The queries look like the following one:

```
GET /xblog/_search
{
  "source": [
    "id",
    "textContent"
  ],
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "textContent": {
        "value": "@([^-A-Za-z0-9])",
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is it's returning also the documents that do not contain a @userMention. I think the @ in the regex is being treated as a special symbol, but reading the documentation I couldn't find how to escape it.

Inthe docs 1, the authors say that you can escape any symbol with double quotes, so I tested:

""@""
But I got nothing.

I also testes expressions I'm used to, like:
/\s([@#][\w_-]+)/g

But that produces multiple errors in Kibana. I tried replacing some parts according to the documentation, but it's still not working.

Can you point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried `"\\@[^-A-Za-z0-9]"`? Or, use `"flags": "NONE"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Another way to write `[^-A-Za-z0-9]` would be `[^[:alnum:]]`. That is probably what I would do.

Comment: @thb ES regex flavor does not support POSIX character classes

Answer (score 2):

You enabled the `ALL` flag that makes `@` match the whole string, see the [ElasticSearch regex documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html):

> If you enable optional features (see below) then these characters may also be reserved:
>
> `# @ & < >  ~`

Then, in the *Any string* section:

> The at sign `"@"` matches any string in its entirety.
> Enabled with the `ANYSTRING` or `ALL` flags.

Since you do not need any special behavior here you may simply tell the engine to use a  "simple" regex by passing `"flags": "NONE"`, or escape the `@`, `"\\@([^-A-Za-z0-9])"`:

> Any reserved character can be escaped with a backslash `"\*"` including a literal backslash character: `"\\"`

And since you need a whole string match, you may need to add `.*` on both ends (to match strings *containing* your match):

```
"query": {
  "regexp": {
    "textContent": {
      "value": ".*@[^-A-Za-z0-9].*",
      "flags": "NONE"
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
"query": {
  "regexp": {
    "textContent": {
      "value": ".*\\@[^-A-Za-z0-9].*",
      "flags": "ALL"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Wilktor, I tryed but it's returning 0 matches. So, both alternatives are not working for me (And I have a lot of text with @) :(

Comment: @gal007  Are you sure you are using the right pattern? I just focused on the problem you described rather than looking for the right pattern, and just took `"value": "@([^-A-Za-z0-9])"` for granted. What should it match? Probably you want to use `@[-A-Za-z0-9]`, not `@[^-A-Za-z0-9]`. That is, remove `^` from the regexes above.

Comment: Hi Wilktor, it seems like the @ is not being detected. I'm running ".*\\@[-A-Za-z0-9].*" with "flags": "NONE" and I have 0 matches. If I remove the @, let's say "value": ".*[-A-Za-z0-9].*", I got more than 30.000 matches.

Comment: @gal007 If you escape, use `".*\\@[-A-Za-z0-9].*"` with `flags` set to `ALL`.

Comment: Even if I do "value": ".*@[^-A-Za-z0-9].*", with "flags": "NONE", I got nothing

Comment: Ok, try also `".*[@][-A-Za-z0-9].*"` with any flags.

Comment: 0 matches with "value": ".*[@][-A-Za-z0-9].*", "flags": "NONE"

Comment: Even the "*." are not working. If I use "value": "[Lyon]", "flags": "ALL", I got many matches. Then, if I use "*.[Lyon]*.", I got nothing. Even if I use the ALL plag.